# Shopify: Add validations in Admin Order Creation

Tags: shopify, admin

We need to add validations in the admin order creation, does anyone know how we can implement it?

When the admin creates an order in the admin, I need to add some validations in the address fields, items in the cart, etc. It's possible? What is the approach?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the admin behaviours. You could be a little more specific. What actual validation problem do you have that cannot be solved by just being a little more careful on the keyboard?

Comment: I want to add validations like po boxes, exclude states, phone number and address length, phone number digits, days in transit, etc. It's a good idea to replicate all the admin order creation in an app? or I should look for another platform?

Comment: You can edit mistakes in Shopify. Why bother with validations on top of what is already provided? Mostly what you'll be adding on will probably make the whole thing crappier, not better.